Why is my .blend file in Godot transparent at a side view
I used MineWay to export a part of my minecraft world into blender. From there I used MCPrep for textures, and exported the blend file to godot. The textures look fine as long as i dont look at the center.
Model Transparency
I tried enabling and disabling backface culling. I turned on face orientation and the whole thing is blue on the outside. I'm new to both Blender and Godot.
UPDATE: for anyone else that has this issue try this. Go to material properties and scroll down to settings. Drop down the box and look for Blend Mode. Change it to Opaque. Mine was on Alpha Hashed and that caused the transparency.

Wild guess but try flipping/recalculating your normals in blender and see if that helps

I tried that and it didn't work BUT i noticed some of my textures were using a blend mode 'Opaque' and 'Alpha Hashed'. changing to A.H. resulted in everything transparent and Opaque as solid!

then you should mark your answer as accepted :)

For anyone else that has this issue try this. Go to material properties and scroll down to settings. Drop down the box and look for Blend Mode. Change it to Opaque. Mine was on Alpha Hashed and that caused the transparency.
